# LINQ Specified Cast Not Valid

Tags: asp.net, linq

Not getting much info on this error, but I'm not using any casting in this specific code, so I'm pretty lost.

```
        var dsn = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"].Split('.').First();
        using (var ctx = new SharedDataContext("switchcurrent"))
        {
            var dbDsn = ctx.SiteObjects.FirstOrDefault(s => s.DSN == dsn);

            if (dbDsn == null)
            {
                Session["CurrentDsn"] = "SwitchCurrent";
            }
            else
            {
                Session["CurrentDsn"] = dbDsn.DSN;
                Response.Redirect(String.Format("~/{0}", dbDsn.DefaultPage));
            }
        }
```

The LINQ statement is where I'm getting the error. If the statement returns null, the code continues fine, but if it's an actual match with an object in the database, I'm getting this error.

EDIT (additional info)

The error message is an InvalidCastException 
Stack trace:

```
 at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query, QueryInfo  queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object lastResult)at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries) at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)at System.Data.Linq.Table`1.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate) at WebApplication1.Default.SetCurrentDsn() in C:\Code\dir\Default.aspx.cs:line 163 at WebApplication1.Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Code\dir\Default.aspx.cs:line 32 at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean     includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

SiteObject.Dsn is a string. and so is dsn.

Basically if it is 'localhost' (which isn't in the db) the code passes, but if its a match ('pgande') this error is thrown.

Comment: What error? Is this a runtime exception or a compiler error? If it is a runtime exception, please post the information about this exception, such as message, exception type and stack trace (and possible inner exceptions). If it is a compile error, please show the exact error message en compiler error number and the exact line.

Comment: What's the type of SiteObjects.DSN?

Comment: which line do you mean by, the linq statement?

Comment: var dbDsn = ctx.SiteObjects.FirstOrDefault(s => s.DSN == dsn);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up dropping the table back into my Data Context and everything is working. Obviously something was corrupt with the table that was dropped in there the first time.

Answer (score 1):

If `s.DSN` cannot be cast to `dsn`, you'll get this error. You may need to supply a conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  var dbDsn = ctx.SiteObjects.FirstOrDefault(s => s.DSN.ToString() == dsn.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you already tried, but may be you need to cast dsn, not s.DSN? Try something link "s => s.DSN == dsn.ToString()".
Did this help?

Comment: Makes no difference, dsn is definitely a string. That's what's making this so hard, 'localhost' returns null from the query and won't break the code, but 'pgande' which should not return null from the query is breaking.